# How to produce a polar contour plot that reads data from an excel spreadsheet?

Tags: excel, python-3.x, matplotlib, contour, polar-coordinates

I am currently doing my internship program in a company and my educational background is actually Petroleum Geoscience, nothing related to programming. So I apologize for any mistakes that I have made or I am about to make.

I was tasked by my supervisor to produce a polar contour plot just like the example below. The example below was generated from the OriginPro (Trial), after the trial period expires I couldn't use the commercial software anymore to produce polar contour plots so I really need help in producing the exactly the same plot in python with different set of data in the future.

[image]

The data imported for this plot are from an excel spreadsheet, there is no problem in importing data from the spreadsheet and plot heat map and contour map, the problem only arises when I attempted to produce a polar contour plot from the data given. From what I read, it is because for heat map and contour map it is projected on Cartesian plane which makes it pretty straight forward, but for polar plots you need a certain form of calculation to change from Cartesian coordination to polar coordination? please correct me if I'm wrong.

This is what happened when i tried in python, it should be looking like the example ive given above

[image: ![enter image description here]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x9rXq.png)

and this is the script that I used for the failed plotting

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


x = df_ODD.loc[:, 'Azimuth'].values.reshape(19,74)
y = df_ODD.loc[:, 'Inclination'].values.reshape(19,74)
z = df_ODD.loc[:, 'Values'].values.reshape(19,74)

f, ax = plt.subplots(subplot_kw=dict(projection='polar'))

plt.contour(x,y,z)


ax.set_theta_zero_location("N")
ax.set_theta_direction(-1)

cb = fig.colorbar(cax)
cax = ax.contourf(theta, r, values, 30)
cb.set_label("Normalized deviatoric stress")


plt.show()
```

Below is the form of data imported from the excel spreadsheet if you are wondering, only the columns labelled as "X" , "Y" and "Z", ignore the column labelled as "β, Azimuth". The rows of data stretches down until 1400++ rows.

[image: ![enter image description here]][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SYRyY.png)

I really need help in solving this problem, I hope any of you could give me a hand. Thanks

Below is the plot i get after changing the degrees to radians.

[image]

and here is the script, i added the mathematical function of converting degrees to radians

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math

x = df_ODD.loc[:, 'Azimuth'].values.reshape(19,74)
y = df_ODD.loc[:, 'Inclination'].values.reshape(19,74)
z = df_ODD.loc[:, 'Values'].values.reshape(19,74)

xi = x * math.pi/180
yi = y * math.pi/180
zi = z * math.pi/180

f, ax = plt.subplots(subplot_kw=dict(projection='polar'))

plt.contour(xi,yi,zi) # choose 20 contour levels, just to show how good its interpolation is
#ax[1].plot(x,y, 'ko ')

ax.set_theta_zero_location("N")
ax.set_theta_direction(-1)

cb = fig.colorbar(cax)
cb.set_label("Normalized deviatoric stress")

#plt.savefig('attempt polar contour.png')

plt.show()
```

Comment: Looks like you provide the angles in degrees, while polar plots would expect radiants as input (radiant = degrees*pi/180 ). However, it's not clear to me if you already have transformed cartesian to polar coordinates or not.

Comment: ahh i see, so maybe i should try changing the degrees to radiants? should i change the degrees to radiant in the data sheet or add the degrees to radians conversion in the python script?

Comment: You can do that in the script in order not to change your original data.

Comment: Hello ImportanceOfBeingErnest, i've already added the mathematical function of converting degrees to radians. The polar contour plot is starting to make sense but if you notice in the image (i added the image above in the body of my question at the bottom, because i don't know how to add images here in the comments, i attached the script too) there is still some distortion in the plotting, some lines are contorted, do you have any idea why is like that? thanks Ernest!

Comment: and i am also not sure of how to make the zenith (is that you call it) to range from 0, 10, 20, 30,... up to 90. Instead of 0.2, 0.4, 0.6,...1.4.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know where those lines come from. Maybe the grid is incomplete, has negative numbers or numbers above 360°, or is otherwise distorted. You can plot it on cartesian coordinates to see if there is anything that would explain this behaviour.

Comment: ahh alright i'll try to figure out the problem, thanks Ernest! you've helped me quite a lot already :D